# Ubuntu 18.04 Install - No “Erase Disk and Install Ubuntu” Option

Tags: xubuntu

I'm trying to install Ubuntu 18.04 from USB on my [Asus Vivobook x509u](https://www.asus.com/Laptops/ASUS-Laptop-15-X509FJ/specifications/). shipped with Windows. When I go through the install process, I never see the screen that has the options for automatic partitioning, such as "Erase disk and install Ubuntu", instead I am taken directly to the manual partitioning screen.

When I manually partition, I get a partitioning failed error message (tried several times including following these steps).

It is a new laptop with pre install windows. there is only one partition c-drive or we can say OS drive.

I can't install Ubuntu at all with this issue, does anyone know why this would occur and how I can get around it?

Comment: 1) The Xubuntu tag is selected, yet you refer to Ubuntu in the Subject line and body text. Which are you using?  2) Did you validate the downloaded ISO file before creating the LiveUSB to install with? The ISO file you use to create a LiveUSB should be checked for download errors by https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-how-to-verify-ubuntu#0 .

Comment: sorry for Xubuntu tag, I have checked the ISO from the link and the response is "OK", I also successfully installed Ubuntu in different PC with the same ISO file

Answer (score 0):

It shouldn't happen, but here is a workaround: boot from the installation media and select "try ubuntu" (or whatever the corresponding choice is for xubuntu). Open a shell, and run `sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/nvme0n1 bs=1024k count=1`. This clears the beginning of the disk. Reboot and install. If your laptop has a SATA drive, use `/dev/sda` instead of `/dev/nvme0n1`.

Needless to say, this will also blow the EFI partition, and probably any recovery partition your laptop may have, so if you plan on ever reinstalling windows, boot windows first and see if you can create a set of recovery media.

Comment: Thanks @JayEye, but I want to install Ubuntu along side windows. so can't erase the os partition. is there any alternative way to resolve that. while I doing googling I found a way something like change sata drive configration  from raid to ahci. but there is no such thing in asus bios to change sata configration.
( Storage: PCIe Gen3x2 NVMe 256GB M.2 SSD + 1x 2.5-inch SATA slot for storage expansion)

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specify that you wanted to keep windows on the laptop.

As it ships, the windows partition takes up the entire disk. What you can do is boot into windows, go to disk management panel (whatever it's called), and shrink the windows partition. That will leave free space on the disk, which you can then use for Linux.

As always, if you have important data on your machine, back them up (you should do that anyway, regardless of whether you are installing Linux or not!). And make sure you have recovery media so that you can restore the machine to its original configuration if something goes really wrong.